# Create a generic class for classes with alternative propertynames?

Tags: c#, generics, nhibernate-mapping

I have a couple of classes. Currently these classes are copies of the same thing except with a few of the properties refer to a different class and have different propertynames which cannot be changed due to mappings in NHibernate.

Simplified version:

```
public class SalesInvoiceDocument
{
   Guid Id { get; set; }
   string Description  { get; set; }
   SalesInvoiceIdentifier SalesInvoice { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseInvoiceDocument
{
   Guid Id { get; set; }
   string Description  { get; set; }
   PurchaseInvoiceIdentifier PurchaseInvoiceId { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to create a generic class of these classes, but the problem I'm struggling with is the fact that the Identifier-properties are both mapped in NHibernate as components and I cannot change the names due to a legacy database.

My mapping looks like this:

```
public class PurchaseInvoiceDocumentMapping : ClassMapping<PurchaseInvoiceDocument>
{
  Id(x => x.Id, map => map.Generator(MappingsHelper.Guid));
  Property(x => x.Description);
  Component(x => x.PurchaseInvoiceId);
}
```

in the table the fields defined in the component are prefixed with the component property name. If I change this to a generic name, the table should be changed as well.

Is there a way to create a generic class with a defineable property name? I know the type of the property is (change the SalesInvoiceIdentifier and PurchaseInvoiceIdentifier to type T), and the name probably not... but still.. how can I work around this? Is it possible?

Regards, Ted